# Display text in autocomplete search in jquery using mongodb

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb

I have the following schema:

```
var Person = new Schema({
    about: { // the array comes from front end
        name: {
            type: String
        },
        places: [{
            type: String
        }]
    },
});
```

... where the given value is:

```
name : 'ram',
places : ['delhi','agra']
```

In autocomplete search, when I enter `'del'` it shows `'delhi,agra'`

When I enter `'del'`, how do I let it only show `'delhi'`, instead?

Comment: You will want to show us your autocomplete code as well so that we can point out where you will need your revisions. If you don't show us your current logic, we can't really tell you where you're tripping up.

Comment: i use code from here  http://physalix.com/jquery-autocomplete-search-with-node-js-and-mongoose/

Comment: That doesn't help. You're showing an unmodified version of the code, but your use case is different and may use a different document structure. We need to see your code, not someone else's.